# How to count identical 1 kb blocks of 2 files in c?

Tags: c

I want to count the 1kb blocks of 2 files and print out the number of identical blocks of these 2 files. I tried to read with fread 1kb blocks but when I tried to compare them I got stuck. I tried to compare the 1 kb blocks with strcmp but that won't work because strcmp is expecting a const char*, is there a way to convert a size_t to a const char*? or is there a better way to compare the blocks?
So fare I wrote this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fin;
    FILE *fin2;
    char block[1024];
    char block2[1024];
    int result;
    int count=0;
    int count_b_file1=0;
    int  count_b_file2=0;
    fin=fopen("file1","r");
    fin2=fopen("file2","r");
    size_t s_file1;
    size_t s_file2;
    while( (! feof(fin)) && (! feof(fin2))){
        s_file1=fread(block,1,sizeof(block),fin);
        count_b_file1=count_b_file1+1;
        s_file2=fread(block2,1,sizeof(block2),fin2);
        count_b_file2=count_b_file2+1;
        result=strcmp(s_file1,s_file2);
        if (result==0){
            count=count+1;
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fin2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you want `memcmp`, not `strcmp`.

Comment: [“while ( !feof (file) )” is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Wait.... you're calling `strcmp` with two variables of type `size_t`??? How does that make ***any*** sense?  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: After applying the `memcmp` fix [as suggested by others], your code assumes that both files have exactly the same length. Just before the [new] `memcmp` line, you may want: `if (s_file1 != s_file2) break;` You can only get unequal lengths if one file is shorter than the other. And, when you hit that point [in the shorter file], you can never get a further match, so you should stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` is only for comparing NUL-terminated strings.
Do you have any reason to know that your 1Kb blocks are NUL-terminated strings?
If there happens to be a `0x00` byte in the first few bytes of your block, `strcmp` will end prematurely!

`memcmp` will do byte-level comparison of the entire blocks.